# onclick not running when specified in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I click the button, it doesn't run the onclick. I tried it in the console and it worked fine. Can anyone help?

```
function customAlert(message) {
  sect = document.createElement("section");
  sect.className = "alert";
  sect.innerHTML = message + "<br /><br />";

  var but = document.createElement("button");
  but.innerHTML = "Gotcha.";
  but.onclick = "document.body.removeChild(sect);";

  sect.appendChild(but);
  document.body.appendChild(sect);

}
```

Comment: the value of onclick should be a function, not a string.

Comment: @scunliffe It can be a string, just like putting the attribute into HTML `<button onclick="somestring">`. But it will be executed in the global scope.

Comment: *If* it works in some cases... as a string... I consider that to be a fluke (and likely global due to an quick 'casting' to a function (e.g. eval()). From the docs its clear that it should be a function reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this syntax:

```
but.onclick = function () {
    document.body.removeChild(sect);
}
```

So, onClick is a `property`. This means that is has some value. When `btn` is clicked, javascript (the browser) calls this property, but it expects it to be a function, some code to be executed. Instead, it "sees" a string and does not know what to do with it.

Comment: Please add an explanation of _why_ the original syntax doesn't work and this does.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: The explanation is not quite right. It knows what to do with a string, it executes it, as with `eval(string)`. The reason it doesn't work is because variables are evaluated in the global scope, and he wants to access the local variable `sect`.

Comment: I created an online JS Fiddle test for this http://jsfiddle.net/g5hdfpa8/10/ I don't think the string option works at all (at least in standards mode in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE10)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm working on a little game and this helped a lot! <3 Stackoverflow! The community is comprised of the best people ever!